# What are the generating cofibrations of the canonical model structure on Cat?

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

It sais [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat) that the canonical model structure on $Cat$ is cofibrantly generated. I found out that a generating trivial cofibration is the functor $I:*\rightarrow E $, where $E$ is the category with 2 isomorphic objects (and $*$ is mapped into one of them), but i can't find any information about the set of generating cofibrations (and I don't know how to work it out on my own). Any suggestion?

More in general does anyone know a book/article in which this argument is treated extensively?

Comment: A reference for this is Rezk's article “A model structure on categories”.

Comment: Are you sure the title is correct? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: "A model category for categories". It's available [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/papers.html).

Comment: @LK512: What Zhen Lin said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generating cofibrations are the inclusions $\emptyset \hookrightarrow \{ \ast \}$ and $\{ 0, 1 \} \hookrightarrow \{ 0 \to 1 \}$ plus the projection $\{ 0 \rightrightarrows 1 \} \to \{ 0 \rightarrow 1 \}$. It is easy to see that a functor has the right lifting property with respect to these if and only if it is fully faithful and surjective on objects.